# AES encryp-decrypt is not working properly --Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt an arbitrary text with RSA, but as I read, RSA dont allow to long texts, so firsts, I need to encrypt with AES-256 (for example), then encrypt the AES key with RSA public, add the encrypted text(with AES), and send the message.

At this moment, I'm doing the AES enc-dec. But I'm doing something wrong because is not decrypting the message properly:

First I generate the AES Key:

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(KEY_SIZE_AES);
this.secretKey_AES = keyGenerator.generateKey();
return this.secretKey_AES;
```

then I encrypt the message:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey_AES);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String encryptedMessage = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encryptedMessage;
```

and finally I decrypt it:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey_AES);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(message,Base64.DEFAULT));
String decryptedMessage = new String(Base64.encode(decrypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
return decryptedMessage;
```

But the decrypted text is not the same as the original. I'm missing somthing?
Or I forget some step?

Example:

[image]

Comment: `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` uses defaults which is a common source of portability problems. Always provide the full "alg/mode/padding" specification.

Comment: thanks, I'll change on monday ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working properly, but you are encoding the result in BASE64. (`"Elias"` is `"RWxpYXM"` in base64). Just change

```
 String decryptedMessage = new String(Base64.encode(decrypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

with

```
String decryptedMessage = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
```

Note that this method will only work for text strings

Comment: Worked perfect. I missunderstood how worked Base64 ^^. Thanks for all